# Where can I download the latest version of VSLangProj150

Tags: visual-studio-2017, envdte, vssdk

I'm looking for the current version of `VSLangProj150.dll` but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I have this version, VSLangProj150.15.0.26228 retrieved from nuget but I believe this is an old version because: 1) it was published on 4/13/2017 and 2) it only contains a single interface called `PackageReferences` which is empty and a `VsProjReferencesPropId150` enum with only two values.

Today, I've installed VS 2017 v15.5 and included the Visual Studio SDK component, but I can't seem to find the dll anywhere on my system.

It appears that there is a new version because I've seen references on the web that refers to `VSProject4` and `Reference6` which are defined in `VSLangProj150`. And I've found this reference in `NuGet.Clients` that reads:
`AsVsProject4.PackageRefereences?.InstalledPackages`

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Must manually get it from nuget.org using `VSLangProj150 Version 1.0.0` or as I did, I just added the following:

`<package id="VSLangProj150" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />`

to my `packages.config` file and then let VS 2017 automatically restore any of my missing packages!

Comment: I did as what you suggested. But VS failed to restore that package and said "can't find 1.0.0 version from https://api.nuget.org/v4/index.json"

Comment: Fixed, must add feed: https://dotnet.myget.org/F/nuget-volatile/api/v3/index.json